# Proof that chromatic number is $< 9$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G= (V,E)$ be a graph such that: 
$E = E_1 \cup E_2$ 
$G_1 = (V, E_1)$ is planar 
$G_2 = (V, E_2)$ is forest
 Proof that chromatic number is $< 9$

### My observations

Each planar graph has chromatic number $\le 4$. Also each forest has chromatic number $2$ if $|V| > 1$

But how can I connect that and have convince about chromatic number $<9$?

Comment: Note that $4\times 2=8<9$.  Can you see how to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given colorings $C_1$ of $G_1$ and $C_2$ of $G_2$, construct a new coloring $C_1 \times C_2$ where  $C_1 \times C_2(v) = ( C_1(v),C_2(v))$. This is a valid coloring of the graph (check this!). Since there are at most 4 colors in $C_1$ and at most 2 in $C_2$, there are at most 8 in  $C_1 \times C_2$.

Comment: Do you mean coloring in use of colors defined by $2$ numbers?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The new coloring is given by ordered pairs of the first coloring and the second coloring.

Comment: I was asking exactly about that @user113102